# MVC3 create multiple tables on .aspx view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation where in I need to show a bunch of tables on a .aspx view in MVC3 project.

I have to use only tables and no grids 
Please help

EDIT: 
So here'e the situation
I have a .aspx view in my MVC3 project. 
on that I need to show data coming from various tables in databae. 
data from each table will be shown in a different table on the screen

say for example

```
<table for data from table1> <table for data from table2>
<table for data from table3> 
<table for data from table4>
```

I can not use grids to display data 
only thing i need to use is `<table></table>` with div and span

Also I need to show the data using JSON object and not using the model.
I need to keep the page as light as possible

Hope I make my self clear this time.

Comment: my table you mean you are gonna use `<table></table>` and have values insert in each `<td>` manually right ?

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is vague, incomplete and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Yasser: yes you are absolutly right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*disclamier: from what I understood from your so very difficult to understand question, below is the answer.*

You need to have a model something like the one shown below

```
 public class MainModel{

    public ModelForTableA ModelA {get;set;}
    public ModelForTableB ModelB {get;set;}
    public ModelForTableC ModelC {get;set;}
}
```

and have your view return this model filled with different subModel which are now properties to MainModel and then use them in your view as shown below.

```
@model YourAppName.Models.MainModel

<h2>Content from Table A</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.ModelA)
{
    <tr><td>
    @item.Name
    </td></tr>
}

<h2>Content from Table B</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.ModelB)
{
    <tr><td>
    @item.Name
    </td></tr>
}

<h2>Content from Table C</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model.ModelC)
{
    <tr><td>
    @item.Name
    </td></tr>
}
```

Comment: this might be solution for a .cshtml page.. but I m looking for .aspx view.. how can we bring the model on an aspx view.. I am new to MVC so please pardon my small mistakes.

Comment: I need to show the data using JSON object and not through model